# Incrementally displaying PHP output works on localhost, but doesn't work on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have used the following code to incrementally stream PHP output to JavaScript via AJAX:

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

while (@ob_end_flush());

ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
ob_implicit_flush(true);

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
  echo ' ';
}

// show output here
```

This works fine for me on `localhost`, but I've tried with three different remote servers, all of which don't work.

What is the reason for this? I can provide more code as necessary.

Comment: I've found trying to flush your output to be spotty at best. I wouldn't rely on PHP to flush out any sort of "real-time" response. Another technology would better serve that purpose if this is what you're trying to do. I wrote a homegrown platform that receives requests via php, sends to a redis pubsub to be handled by express/nodejs for the real-time delivery. Maybe you should think about a different avenue if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Blake hmm yes, that would sound like a plausible solution. Could you please advise as how I could use Node.JS as an intermediary step for realtime delivery? The data I'm outputting is of a plaintext nature anyways, so that would work fine for me.

Comment: I think that's slightly outside of the scope of this question. I'd encourage you to do some reading on nodejs, or use a service like FireBase if you don't want to manage your own servers. It's tough to give any real advice based on a vague notion of what you want on my part.

Comment: @Blake I've tried a search on `displaying incremental data with Node.JS`, but I haven't found any results. I've already found the `spawn` command for logging data from `php worker.php`, but now I just need to be able to stream this data from Node.JS to an AJAX front-end.

Comment: This is going to take a little longer for you to engineer a solution than a quick google. I can only point you in the right direction on this. PHP/Apache/Nginx's model is to receive the request, serve the request, and close the connection. It's not really designed to keep a continuous connection. Best of luck.